# jQuery UI widget creation scoping issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to call cycle_pages inside of my _create but I'm hitting some scoping issues.  Once I call setTimeout I change to window's scope and not my anonymous function's.  I've tried a handful of things.  The most logical seems to be

```
function cycle_pages(){
    console.log("hello");
    change_page(1);
    setTimeout(function (self) {
        self.cycle_pages();
    }, 1000);
}
```

but I've also tried variations on

```
function cycle_pages(){
    console.log("hello");
    change_page(1);
    setTimeout('cycle_pages()', 1000);
}
```

I've tried moving the function into global scope, but that causes change_page() to be out of scope.

Any tips?  Full paste here http://jsfiddle.net/vn7Re/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) function is not supplied any arguments when it is called so you probably want something more like this:

```
function cycle_pages() {
    var self = this;
    change_page(1);
    setTimeout(function() {
        self.cycle_pages();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I should have added that self = this was declared before.  Good eye.  I'm testing this out now

Comment: I think my code is so far off of the right way to do it that I've backed myself into a corner that isn't fixable.  I'm going to redesign and see if I still have this problem.

Comment: My code definitely had to be rewritten.  I moved everything to a more logical place in the widget.  It made sense now that I had my first jquery UI widget under my belt.  Your answer absolutely answered the question when I redid everything else.  Now this question falls into a category with 500 other questions.  I should have realized I was doing something wrong in the bigger picture to have had the problem I was having with scope.

Answer (score 1):

You could make this even simpler:

```
function cycle_pages(){
    console.log("hello");
    change_page(1);
    setTimeout(cycle_pages, 1000);
}
```

You don't need to make an anonymous function in setTimeout.